# In Luke 23:2, is “an anointed king” a possible translation of «Χριστὸν βασιλέα»?

Tags: greek, luke, grammar

In Luke 23:2, the Greek text states,

> <sup>Βʹ</sup> ἤρξαντο δὲ κατηγορεῖν αὐτοῦ λέγοντες Τοῦτον εὕρομεν διαστρέφοντα τὸ ἔθνος καὶ κωλύοντα Καίσαρι φόρους διδόναι λέγοντα ἑαυτὸν Χριστὸν βασιλέα εἶναι <sup>TR, 1550</sup>

Most English translations translate «Χριστὸν βασιλέα» as “Christ, a king,”  wherein Χριστὸν is functioning as a substantive. However, the [Revised Version](https://ia800207.us.archive.org/31/items/cu31924029309717/cu31924029309717.pdf) includes in the footnote “Or *an anointed king*.”

[image: Luke 23:2, Revised Version]

Does the grammar allow the translation of «Χριστὸν βασιλέα» as “an anointed king,” where Χριστὸν is functioning as an adjective rather than a substantive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The word [χριστός is actually a verbal adjective of χρίω](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0058%3Aentry%3Dxristo%2Fs). Verbal adjectives are types of adjectives that are formed from verbs by adding a suffix—usually τέος or τός. In the former (τέος) the accent is always on the penult, and I assume that in the latter (τός) the accent is always on the ultima. Thus the word χριστός can definitely be an adjective. Arguably, it is more of an adjective by right. The noun is a substantive use of the verbal adjective.

I think it can be read both ways: as two nouns in apposition ("Christ, a king"), or as an adjective modifying a noun ("anointed king"). I think there is nothing to suggest otherwise. The fact that the editors of the Greek text chose to capitalize χριστὸν is inconsequential, as the original text had all uppercase letters. It is worth mentioning that βασιλέα is an indefinite noun, thus it should be translated as "an anointed king", not "the anointed king".

Comment: If in apposition, wouldn’t it be “a christ, a king”—both being indefinite?

Comment: @SimplyaChristian I think that proper names are different, actually, and the article with them is often optional. You can read more about it here if you scroll down to "Articles with Proper Names": http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus:text:1999.04.0007:part=4:chapter=40

Comment: @SimplyaChristian In that link, section 1142 deals specifically with the appositive case.

Comment: §1142 is listed under the following heading: “THE ARTICLE WITH PROPER NAMES.” That does not apply here, nor does §1142, as there are neither names nor definite articles in the phrase in question. If Χριστὸν were a name (proper noun) and in apposition, wouldn’t it have a definite article? For example, Mark 15:32: ὁ Χριστὸς ὁ βασιλεὺς...

Comment: @SimplyaChristian 1142b ("Deities") says that the article can be used with the name and the epithet or (less often) neither. It gives an example with Zeus where the article is removed. I think this might apply.

Comment: In other words, proper names often do have articles, but it's not necessary.

Comment: I think equating the noun Χριστός to Ζεύς is a bit of a stretch. That does not seem how the people accusing Jesus understood it at all.

Comment: @SimplyaChristian I agree, it is a stretch. But I think what I'm getting at is, that no matter how you slice it, names often lack definite articles. If you look at this text from Thucydides, the names of both Alexander and his son often lack the article: http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.01.0199%3Abook%3D2%3Achapter%3D99

Comment: @SimplyaChristian I think the logic might be that names are implicitly definite, as they specify a definite person. But having established that definite articles are optional with proper names, I think it would require a separate question to explain the reasons why.